# asp.net dynamic data scaffold using a NoSQL DB

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, nosql, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

Is there any way to use ASP.NET Dynamic Data WebApp or Scaffold using a NoSQL DB (CouchDB)
I have a Class library of Objects - marked as a ContextModel.

I think i have to generate an EDMX file from my object Model - but I'm not sure how.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you want is to create a custom scaffolding.  Steven Sanderson has a great series on MvcScaffolding and one of the [articles is devoted to this topic](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/04/07/mvcscaffolding-creating-custom-scaffolders/).  So you would do something like

```
> scaffold CustomScaffolder CouchRepository
```

if you want to set this as the default repository:

```
> Set-DefaultScaffolder Repository CouchRepository
```

You wouldn't need to generate an EDMX, as you don't need EntityFramework.
Just be sure to use the "-Repository" switch when you scaffold the controllers.  See this [article](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/01/28/mvcscaffolding-one-to-many-relationships/)